# how to move last picturebox for snake game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I want to make my own Snake game with C#. I allready started a couple of times (like 2 or 3 times) but the breaks between where too great so it appeared easier to write the code new then trying to understand the existing code (I know, therefor comments exist, but sometimes I'm way into coding and forget the comments totally).
So now I want to make the final try. I have some thoughts on almost everything allready, but I have no clue how I can figure out what the last picturebox of my snake is! Generally the snakes body consists of many PictureBoxes and everytime it eats the food one PictureBox is added at the end. 
To move the snake across the screen I want to take the last PictureBox (at the end of the snakes body) and move it to the front of the Snake so it becomes the snakes head. The body would be generated by the code, so to keep track of all the boxes I could use a list. But I have no clue how I can find out which box is the last one and if I found out, how I could move only this box to the beginning of the snake.

I would appreciate every tip you could give,
thank you for taking your time to read this! :)

Comment: If you want to make a video game in c# I would recommend using something like Unity.

Comment: I irst want to make some simple games without engines before I try something like Unity or Unreal ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no clue how I can find out which box is the last one and if I found out, how I could move only this box to the beginning of the snake.

Any collection (List, Queue, Stack, etc) or an array can be used to keep track of the order of objects. Your case sounds like it would be best to use a first-in-first-out collection. Queue works on this principle. I'll use strings to illustrate how it works:

```
Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();

queue.Enqueue("one"); //add to queue
//queue is now ["one"]
queue.Enqueue("two"); //queue is now ["one", "two"]
queue.Enqueue("three"); //queue is now ["one", "two", "three"]

string firstString = queue.Dequeue(); //sets string to "one" and removes it from queue
//queue is now ["two", "three"]
queue.Enqueue("four"); //queue is now ["two", "three", "four"]
queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue()); //moves first element to the back of the queue
//queue is now ["three", "four", "two"]
```

Queue supports any datatype, you can declare a PictureBox Queue to keep track of your snake.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand generally the Queue thing. But is there a way I can get an Item by Index? So that I can for example grab "one", do something with the object "one", than dequeue it and enqueue it again so it moves from the beginning to the end? And by doing something with the object "one", can I use it directly like queue[0].color or something like that?

Comment: @JDeveloper Queue only supports getting the first item with the `Dequeue()` function. If you want access to all items it's better to use `List<PictureBox> snake` to hold the snake. You can access elements with the square bracket notation `snake[0]`. If you want to move the first element to the back of the list you can do `snake.Add(snake[0]); snake.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: Ok, with List I'm a little bit familiar ... Currently I have no PC which can handle VS to test it, so I have to ask: Can I call PictureBox methods with the code like snake[0]. _PictureBoxMethod_ ?

Comment: @JDeveloper You've got it.